# Cannot save my extracted in R as .csv or as text

Tags: r, json, dataframe, export-to-csv

I wanted to extract data from a package in R called Rdota2. However, when trying to use write.csv on my function, it displays

> Error in as.data.frame.default(heroes) :    cannot coerce class ""dota_api"" to a data.frame.

Is there any way I can convert the file directly using any other package?

The output of my function is displayed on my console. The only thing I am concerned is to save the data in CSV or as text.

Answer (score 0):

The data frame is stored in an element of `heroes`...

```
write.csv(heroes$content, "heroes.csv")
```